# I'm getting an "InvalidOperationException" error

Tags: unity

I want to develop a new football game. I placed a cube called "BallTrigger" in the player's foot area. In this way, I wrote code so that the player can shoot the ball. But when the player hits the ball, he doesn't shoot. It gives the following error;

> InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the
> UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling
> to Input System package in Player Settings.
> Karakter.Update () (at
> Assets/Codes/Karakter.cs:22)

How do I fix this error?

Karakter.cs ;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Karakter : MonoBehaviour

{
public bool ball;
public GameObject ballobj;

public float sut1,sut2;
void Start()
{
    
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (ball) {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            ballobj.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = transform.TransformDirection (new Vector3 (0, 0, Random.Range(sut1,sut2)));
        }
    }
}
}
```

BallTrigger.cs;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = true;
         }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = false;
         }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider nesne){
         if (nesne.gameObject.tag == "Ball") {
            transform.root.gameObject.GetComponent<Karakter> ().ball = true;
         }
        
    }
}
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Problem is solved. File > Build Setting > Player Setting > Other Setting > Active Input Handling = BOTH

Comment: You should use one input system or the other — simultaneously using both is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: What you said is absolutely correct. But I don't quite understand the "NewInputSystem" problem. I'm a beginner in Unity.

Comment: You can edit your original question to ask about how to work with the new input system, and get help with that part.